# Please check my proof on: $\sim$ is an equivalence relation $\Leftrightarrow S<G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

**Problem:** Let $\emptyset\ne S\subset G$, where $G$ is a group, and define a relation on $G$ by $a\sim b\Leftrightarrow ab^{-1}\in S$. Show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation if and only if $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Solution:

$(\Rightarrow)$ $\forall a,b\in S\subset G; a\sim b\Leftrightarrow ab^{-1}\in S$, so $\forall a,b\in S; ab^{-1}\in S$, therefore $S<G$.

$(\Leftarrow)$

- $a\sim a\Leftrightarrow aa^{-1}=e_S \in S$ $\checkmark$

  $a\sim b\Leftrightarrow ab^{-1}\in S\stackrel{*}{\Leftrightarrow} (ab^{-1})^{-1}\in S\Leftrightarrow ba^{-1}\in S\Leftrightarrow b\sim a$ $\checkmark$

  $a\sim b\Leftrightarrow ab^{-1}\in S \wedge b\sim c\Leftrightarrow bc^{-1}\in S$, so $(ab^{-1})(bc^{-1})\stackrel{**}{\in} S\Leftrightarrow a(b^{-1}b)c^{-1}\in S\Leftrightarrow ac^{-1}\in S\Leftrightarrow a\sim c$ $\checkmark$

$*: \text{Because }S<G.$

$**$: Because $S$ is a group, therefore a semigroup, and therefore closed.

Please tell me where I'm wrong or answer if there's another approach.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that for the $\Rightarrow$ direction, you are expected to make use of the antecedent: namely, the fact that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $G$, meaning, it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

It is true that for non-empty subset $S$ of $G$ such that $\forall a,b\in S; ab^{-1}\in S$ suffices to affirm that $S\leq G$, but unless you've already encountered that in an earlier exercise, or as a theorem to work with, then I believe that the intent of the problem is, in part, to prove that fact.

The $\Leftarrow$ direction of your proof is just fine! Nice work.

Comment: I've got that as a theorem in the book. Thanks!